# Choose time zone after sysprep

Tags: windows, sysprep, windows-8.1

Is it possible to file unattend.xml setting to be able to choose a time zone from the list?

Please give me some advice

My file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">

    <settings pass="oobeSystem">

       <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <InputLocale>en-US </InputLocale>

            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>

            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>

            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>

            <UserLocale>en-US</U serLocale>

        </component>

        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <OEMInformation>

                <Manufacturer>YXC</Manufacturer>

                <SupportURL>http://www.yxc.com</SupportURL>

            </OEMInformation>

            <OOBE>

                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>

                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>

                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>

            </OOBE>

            <UserAccounts>

                <AdministratorPassword>

                    <Value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Value>

                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>

                </AdministratorPassword>

                <LocalAccounts>

                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">

                        <Password>

                            <Value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Value>

                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>

                        </Password>

                        <Description>Admin</Description>

                        <DisplayName>Admin</DisplayName>

                        <Group>Administrators</Group>

                        <Name>Admin</Name>

                    </LocalAccount>

                </LocalAccounts>

            </UserAccounts>

            <WindowsFeatures>

                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>

                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>

            </WindowsFeatures>

            <RegisteredOrganization>Some name</RegisteredOrganization>

            <RegisteredOwner>Some name</RegisteredOwner>

            <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>

            <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>

        </component>
    </settings>

    <settings pass="specialize">

        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

           <RegisteredOrganization>Some name</RegisteredOrganization>

            <RegisteredOwner>Some name</RegisteredOwner>

            <ProductKey>YXCVB-YXCVB-YXCVB-YXCVB-YXCVB</ProductKey>

        </component>

    </settings>

    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim://tsclient/e/sources/install.wim#Windows 8.1 ENTERPRISE" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi"/>

</unattend>
```

Comment: As sccm rides on the back of sysprep and unattend, and it's possible there, I have to say yes, despite lack of absolute proof.

Comment: Your paste came out horribly mangled. Please try it again, using the _code_ {} button to format it (not the _quote_ " button).

Comment: What is the *exact* command line you're running to perform the `sysprep`?

Comment: sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /shutdown

Answer (score 4):

Sure, do it in the "specialize" pass:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <!-- snip -->
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    <!-- snip -->
    </settings>
    <!-- snip -->
</unattend>
```

TechNet has additional details for the [Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715801.aspx) component and [TimeZone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715394.aspx).